# EditText clean on first touch issue

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` that contains a grey text that indicates what the user have to input, when clicked the first time this text must be cleared to allow the user to input the content without waste time to clear the hint text.

so I have added a listener with this code:

```
 if(!editCountryEdited){
     editCountryEdited=true;
     editCountry.setText("");
     //...
 }
```

But unfortunately works only is the `EditText` is clicked a second time after the first click. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use hint http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:hint="Your grey text here" />
```

Comment: I also suggest adding `editCountry.setHint("Your grey text here");`

Comment: i have totally ignored this feature. Thanks! I'll check this as right answer after the timeout

Answer (score 0):

This is called hint in android use android:hint="Enter Name"
In your  xml

It displays that text when the input field is empty, selected or unselected.

Or assign a onClickListener on the editText and set it empty with setText()

like this 
Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourid);

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.yourid);
        your_field_name.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default feature of EditText [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29)

from java
`myEditText.setHint("your text");`

from xml

`android:hint="Your text"`

You can also find for custom hint for your desire look. For example to change hint text color you can use [setHintTextColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHintTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29)